# Cannot find module '../config/env Failed at 0.1.0 start script

Tags: reactjs, npm, npm-scripts, npm-start

it was working fine yesterday i don't know what happened npm is not starting instead giving the above error. 
    help me pls..

npm start scripts not working pls someone help me i'm new to this field

```
Husnains-Mini:~ husnaintahir$ cd ReactApp
Husnains-Mini:ReactApp husnaintahir$ cd react-complete-guide
Husnains-Mini:react-complete-guide husnaintahir$ npm start

> react-complete-guide@0.1.0 st art /Users/husnaintahir/ReactApp/react-complete-guide
> node scripts/start.js

module.js:549
    throw err;
    ^

Error: Cannot find module '../config/env'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:547:15)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:474:25)
    at Module.require (module.js:596:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:11:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/husnaintahir/ReactApp/react-complete-guide/scripts/start.js:15:1)
    at Module._compile (module.js:652:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:663:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:565:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:505:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:497:3)
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! react-complete-guide@0.1.0 start: `node scripts/start.js`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the react-complete-guide@0.1.0 start script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /Users/husnaintahir/.npm/_logs/2019-05-22T04_42_05_832Z-debug.log
Husnains-Mini:react-complete-guide husnaintahir$
```

Comment: Error: Cannot find module '../config/env' tells you quite a bit. It expects there to be a file called either env.js or similar in a config-folder one level up

Comment: what is the solution for this problem? I have the same issue at the moment.